# Multiple material on single obj file with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, objloader

I'm using three.js to load an obj file, a ring with some pearls. I haven't got an `mtl` file, as the software we use to export the `obj` (rhinoceros(?)) won't generate it with an `obj` file (this is what I was told by the graphic designer).

I need to set a metallic material ONLY for the ring, and glass material ONLY for the stone/pearls.

This is a link to the test page where I actually load the file:
[jaaxlab.com/test_youring](http://jaaxlab.com/test_youring)

...for the rest I don't know how to set a single material and also multiple.

Link to obj file [jaaxlab.com/test_youring/obj/prova1.obj](http://jaaxlab.com/test_youring/obj/prova1.obj)

Comment: There is no code to post, i have to understand if is possible to do one thing or not... and how, i can show how i'm loading the obj file but i don't think it is needed

Comment: Could you share a link for downloading of you obj file?

Comment: this is it http://jaaxlab.com/test_youring/obj/prova1.obj @prisoner849

Comment: I edited the question with some minor grammatical changes, added the link from the comments, and removed the intro/closing paragraphs, to keep the question succinct. Good luck!

Comment: I see the following error: `(index):139 Uncaught ReferenceError: rObj is not defined
    at OBJLoader2Example.initGL ((index):139)
    at (index):274` in the console. Maybe that's a starting point for helping to debug :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object has several children. The child with index 0 is the ring. Also, its name is `sezione_B_misura13_Riviera_mix_full anello_sezione_B_misura13`.

So, you can access it like:

```
obj.children[0].material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial(...);
```

or

```
obj.getObjectByName('sezione_B_misura13_Riviera_mix_full anello_sezione_B_misura13').material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial(...);
```

Given that `obj` is the object, loaded with you loader.

Take a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/ch1fxdL4/). Load your file, then check the console log. You can also click any part of the object and see its id and name in the console.

Comment: Okay thanks, it seems to work, but i don't know how to add material in my code, every example i found online to work with obj file use different code and i don't know where to start, can you give me a hint?

Comment: @gattass69 I changed the answer. Don't forget that you have to have light sources in your scene, if you use a material different from `THREE.MeshBasicMaterialI()`.

Comment: what do you mean with "light sources"? A light in the scene? Anyway thanks, i'll try right now

Comment: @gattass69 Well, yes, "lights" :)